# LinkedList implementation. Class contains its own object

Tags: java

folks, the implementation of the `LinkedList` causes me a little of misunderstanding. I know how to implement all of the methods of the `LinkedList` but I do not understand why the class `Link` contains its own object inside itself (inside the class `Link`). Could smb please explain why class `Link` contains its own object inside it? Is there any analogy? Thanks in advance!

Class `Link`

```
package LinkedList;

public class Link {

    public String data;
    public Link next;

    public Link(String data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

Class `LinkedList`

    class LinkedList{

        public Link firstLink;

        public LinkedList(){
            this.firstLink = null;
        }

        public void insert(String data){
            Link myLink = new Link(data);
            myLink.next = firstLink;
            firstLink = myLink;
        }

        public Link deleteFirst(){
            Link deletedLink = firstLink;
            firstLink = firstLink.next;
            return deletedLink;
        }

        public boolean search(String data){
            Link current = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.data.equals(data)){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void displayList(){
            Link current = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                current.display();
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

    }
```

Class `LinkedTester`

```
package LinkedList;

public class LinkTester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList theLinkedList = new LinkedList();
        theLinkedList.insert("A");
        theLinkedList.insert("B");
        theLinkedList.insert("C");
        theLinkedList.insert("D");
        theLinkedList.insert("E");

        theLinkedList.displayList();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(theLinkedList.search("A"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the basic idea of a linked list. Have a look at this [Wiki-Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). The inner list is not an object, but a reference!

Comment: Think of the chain like a line of elephants, with each elephant holding the tail of the one ahead of it. You ask an Elephant what he's holding onto, and he answers, "the next Elephant." Same idea, but with Links instead of Elephants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to understand that when you declare

```
public link next;
```

`next` is not an object of the class `link`, it is a variable that can point to the object of class `link` and when you do `next = new link();` that is when an object is created and `next` starts pointing to an object.

So, what this actually means is, your class `list` does not contain an object of it own type, but contains a variable that can point to an object of the `list` type, which is the basic concept of Linked List (One node pointing to another node, forming a continuous chain)